# Use USB-Sound-Device with VLC on Headless RaspPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, vlc, headless, cvlc

I've got a headless Rasberry Pi with a USB Sound Device. I want to play mp3 files with VLC.

aplay -l gives me

```
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And i try to start vlc this way(s)

```
cvlc --vout none --alsa-audio-device card\ 1 --play-and-exit sound.mp3
cvlc --vout none -aout usb --play-and-exit sound.mp3
cvlc --vout none --alsa-audio-device DEV=1 --play-and-exit sound.mp3
```

none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need `hw:1,0` (pure hardware device) or `plughw:1,0` (standard plugin for resampling in front of hardware device) as ALSA device name for your card 1 subdevice 0, or you can do `aplay -L` and have a look at all standard device names (which will include channel selection and more)

Comment: Could you be more specific? How should this `hw:1,0` option be specified?